# NDSolve with piecewise boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, discontinuity

I am trying to solve two simultaneous partial differential equation for $P[x,t]$ and $V[x,t]$. I have a piecewise boundary condition for $V[L,t]$. When using that piecewise condition, I get the error

> NDSolve::ndnum : Encountered  non-numerical value for a derivative at t==0

However, I get a solution when I manually solve within the piecewise ranges.

```
Vout = 
  Piecewise[
    {{1.1182586384 t, 0 <= t <= 1}, {1.11826, 1 <= t <= 14}, 
     {644.41640535 (0.00173530 - 0.00173530 (-14 + t)), 14 <= t <= 15}}];

NDSolve[
  {D[P[x, t], t] + 7.17358*^8 D[V[x, t], x] == 0, 
   D[V[x, t], t] + D[P[x, t], t]/1000 == 
     Piecewise[
       {{-0.00984252 Abs[V[x, t]] V[x, t], 0 < x < 3100}, 
        {-0.00656168 Abs[V[x, t]] V[x, t], 3100 < x < 5800}, 
        {-0.02249719 Abs[V[x, t]] V[x, t], 5800 < x < 5809.144}}],
   V[x, 0] == 0., P[x, 0] == 3.4474*^7, P[0, t] == 3.447*^7, V[5809.144, t] == Vout}, 
  {P, V}, {x, 0, 5809.144}, {t, 0, 15}]
```

Comment: Did you try defining Vout as a function? Specifically use `Vout[t_?NumericQ]:=...` to make sure it is only evaluated with numeric values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that by limiting the domain of `Vout` to `0 <= t < 15`, its derivative becomes `Indeterminate` at the boundaries `t = 0, 15`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can fix it by extending the definition of `Vout` beyond the time interval.  The extension won't be used, except in values of its derivative at the endpoints of the time interval.

```
Clear[x, t, V, P];
Vout = Piecewise[{
    {1.1182586384 t, t <= 1},
    {1.11826, 1 <= t <= 14},
    {644.41640535 (0.00173530 - 0.00173530 (-14 + t)), 14 <= t}}];

NDSolve[{
  D[P[x, t], t] + 7.17358*^8 D[V[x, t], x] == 0,
  D[V[x, t], t] + D[P[x, t], t]/1000 == Piecewise[{
     {-0.00984252 Abs[V[x, t]] V[x, t], 0 < x < 3100},
     {-0.00656168 Abs[V[x, t]] V[x, t], 3100 < x < 5800},
     {-0.02249719 Abs[V[x, t]] V[x, t], 5800 < x < 5809.144}}],
  V[x, 0] == 0., P[x, 0] == 3.4474*^7, P[0, t] == 3.447*^7, V[5809.144, t] == Vout},
 {P, V}, {x, 0, 5809.144}, {t, 0, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]