# Problem with using NDSolve on wave PDE on string

Tags: differential-equations, discontinuity

I am trying to verify my hand solution for wave PDE in 1D, on a string. The solution I get from `NDSolve` does not match the analytical solution.

This is a string, fixed on left end, and free to move on the right. There is damping involved. (from air motion). The damping is set to be critical for mode 1 only.  The string is pulled up for initial position, but has zero initial velocity:

Solving the wave PDE on string $t>0,0<x<L$
$$
u_{tt}+bu_{t}=c^{2}u_{xx}\qquad0<x<L,t>0
$$
Boundary conditions
\begin{align*}
u\left(  0,t\right)   &  =0\\
\left.  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\vert _{x=L} &  =0
\end{align*}
Initial conditions, $t=0$
\begin{align*}
u_{t}\left(  x,0\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =f\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}
Using 
\begin{align*}
f\left(  x\right)   &  =\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{ccc}
\frac{3h}{L}x &  & 0<x<\frac{L}{3}\\
h &  & \frac{L}{3}<x<L
\end{array}
\right.  \\
b &  =\frac{4\pi}{3}\\
c &  =4\\
L &  =3\\
h &  =\frac{1}{10}
\end{align*}
Hence the PDE becomes $u_{tt}+\frac{4\pi}{3}u_{t}=16u_{xx}$.

I get warnings from `NDSolve` which I need help to get rid of them. I think they are what cause the numerical solution not to look the same as the analytical.

Here is what I tried

```
ClearAll[x, t, f];
L = 3; c = 4; h = 1/10; b = Pi*c/L;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3*h/L*x, 0 < x < L/3}, {h, L/3 < x < L}}];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, L}]  (*Initial position*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pde = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + b D[u[x, t], t] == c^2* D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][L, t] == 0};
ic = {Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, u[x, 0] == f[x]};
```

Now, if I just type

```
numericalSol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

It hangs and I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using

```
numericalSol = 
 NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, 2}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 200}}]
```

It does not hang, and gives solution with these warnings

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the solution when animated does not look correct:

```
Manipulate[
 Quiet@Chop@Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. numericalSol], {x, 0, L},
    BaseStyle -> 15,
    ImageMargins -> 3,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
    PlotRange -> {{0, L}, {-0.1, 0.11}},
    ImageSize -> 500,
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "U"}
    ],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 2, 0.01}
 ]
```

[image]

Here is the animation from the analytical solution to compare with

[image]

I understand that `NDSolve` gives `Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` but I do not see why, as I think they are consistent. Free right end mean $u_x(L)=0$ and that is what I used.

Note that `DSolve` can't solve this PDE in V 12:

```
pde = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + b D[u[x, t], t] == c^2* D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][L, t] == 0};
ic = {Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, u[x, 0] == f[x]};
DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

(*no solution*)

Question is: What option to use to make `NDSolve` remove these warning with the hope the result will look like my solution (I think the analytical solution is correct, but there is of course  possibility I made error, that is why I was trying to verify it with `NDSolve`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193688/1871). The definition for `f` is improper, because the default value of `Piecewise` is `0`, which leads to $f(L)=0$. Modifying it to

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{3 h/L x,  x < L/3}}, h]
```

will remove the `ibcinc` warning and make `NDSolve` produce the expected result. (It's still necessary to control the spatial grid size as you've already done, of course. )

Comment: I tried your approach together with `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",...}`  but I get a warning `CoefficientArrays::poly: (u^(1,0))[3,t] is not a polynomial.` What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But I wrote `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3*h/L*x, 0 < x < L/3}, {h, L/3 < x < L}}];` ?.  So zero and L are not included. Your fix works, but I am confused now why. Need to look more at it. May be because it is numerical, then `0<x` is treated as `0<=x` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `"FiniteElement"` method cannot handle the b.c. `Derivative[1, 0][u][L, t] == 0` (at least now), one needs to rewrite it with `NeumannValue`. (BTW, some related discussion can be found in the comments under [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172998/1871). ) (Edit: Oh I forgot it's not necessary to explicitly set zero `NeumannValue`, one can just remove that b.c., as suggested by user21 below. )

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, just delete that `Derivative[1, 0][u][L, t] == 0` boundary condition.

Comment: @Nasser The default value of `Piecewise` is `0` i.e. $f(x)=0$ when $x\ge L$ under your definition.

Comment: I see what you mean. So this also worked `f[x_] = Piecewise[{{3*h/L*x, 0 <= x <= L/3}, {h, L/3 < x <= L}}];` where I changed `x<L` to `x<=L`.  Strange that `DSolve` did not complain that BC and IC are not consistent when I used the old definition of `f[x]`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, FiniteElement seems to be much more robust (concerning the definition of `f[x]`)

Comment: @user21 Thanks, I forgot&learned again the default setting auf `NeumannValue`

Comment: @Nasser Seems that `DSolve` never checks if i.c. and b.c. are consistent?